# Changed my cloud formation IAM group names but old IAM groups don't get removed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I tried changing my iam group names in cloud formation, and the new ones got created, but the old ones didn't get deleted. Is this expected? Should I have to remove these manually? Seems like it should get rid of the old ones automatically. Checking the stack information in the aws console says everything completed successfully.

Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure, you did update the stack & not re-create? While updating, what was the change set like? It usually shows details where resource would be modified in place or replaced.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, @ASR! I was trying to update the stack not re-create it. The first time I ran it, it complained that I didn't have permissions to delete, then the second time it didn't complain anymore but the old IAM groups were still there. Ended up deleting manually.

Answer (score 1):

The `Delete stack` operation is a best effort operation. It deletes whatever resources it can. On retry after `delete failed` gives a warning window listing resources which require manual deletion. So if delete failed on your `IAM groups` first time, you will have to delete them manually. This explanation is only out of experience as I have seen such behavior many times. I do not now if such behavior is documented somewhere.